# Is 2 hours and 5 mins enough time for transfer from international to domestic flight in Melbourne Tullamarine?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-transfer, check-in

I'll be flying from Malaysia to Canberra pretty soon. My flight from malaysia will reach Melbourne at 4.55am while my connecting flight from Melbourne to Canberra is at 7am. Both flights are in the same airport but different terminals (T2 to T3).

I was wondering if 2 hours and 5 mins sufficient for me to go through customs, collect my baggage and re-check-in for my connecting flight to canberra? Or do i need to re-book my flight?

Comment: Are both flights on a single ticket?

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR: You may miss the connection, but it's probably not a big deal if you do.*

2 hours is feasible if all goes well.  Unlike Sydney, all terminals are MEL are directly connected and it's only a few minutes walk from T2 to T3.

However, Immigration and Customs at Melbourne can be quite slow, particularly in the early morning when long-haul flights like yours land.  If you're the citizen of a [SmartGate](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/smartgates/arrivals) country, you can use the automated gates and avoid the long general Immigration queue, but may still be queuing for a while at Customs.

The good news is that MEL-CBR flights are very frequent, running every hour or so on both Qantas and Virgin.  So as long as your flights are on the same ticket, if you miss the connection, they'll put you on the next flight for free.